# Crud Repository get from position until position

Tags: spring, spring-boot, crud, spring-jdbc, spring-repositories

So I have a table of tags. Tag has an id and a name.

As a first step I wanted to sort all the IDs by descending order

`List<Tag> findAllByOrderByIdDesc()`

Next I wanted just to get first three tags and got it done by doing

`List<Tag> findTop3ByOrderByIdDesc()`

Now I want to get all tags in descending order from position x until position x+3 but I can't seem to find or figure out what to do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass Pageable parameter.

Example:

`List<Tag> findTop3ByOrderByIdDesc(Pageable page`);

In the Pageable parameter you need to pass page number and offset.

Consider if you want to get values range from id 20 to 30.

```
PageRequest.of(2,10);
```

pass this as your Pageable parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Pageable is a good idea but you have to use PagingAndSortingRepository or JpaRepository, not CrudRepository.